# Linear transformation on three quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra

This is really easy question on linear algebra but I cannot prove it rigorously however intuitively I know that this is true.

Suppose we have we have three quadratic forms $$b(x_1,x_2,x_3)=X^TBX, d(y_1,y_2,y_3)=Y^TDY, f(z_1,z_2,z_3)=Z^TFZ.$$
And I know that by linear transformations $X=CY$ and $Y=GZ$ quadratic form $d$ is obtained from $b$ and $f$ is obtained from $d$.

How to prove rigorously that $f$ is obtained from $b$ by linear transformation $X=(CG)Z$?

Sorry for this stupid question: I know this fact is true but cannot prove it!

Would be very grateful for an answer!

Answer (score 1):

congruence is an equivalence relation. For symmetric matrices of the same size, congruence means there is a nonsingular square matrix such that $P^T MP = N.$ This is reversible because $P$ has an inverse, so that ${P^{-1}}^T NP^{-1} = M.$

You are saying $$ C^T BC = D $$  and
$$ G^T DG = F $$
So
$$ F = G^T DG = G^T ( C^T B C) G = (CG)^T B (CG)   $$

This is the transitivity property.